# DropDown for Edit() [Razor]View, Pre-Loaded with Data from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, razor

I have the dropdowns in my Create() View working perfect.

But in the Edit() View I can't get the Data that was submited during the Create() to show up in DropDowns with the Value enterened upon Create()

I just have textboxs in place at the moment And would really like to have Data Represented in a dropdown for easy selection.

**Here is one example:**

Create() View - One dropdown is for EmployeeTypes, and stores selected to EmployeeTypeId

Now How do I get that to show up in the Edit() View as the same dropdown, but with Value of EmployeeId already selected?

---

I have a EmployeeViewModel for the Create() View

But I am just passing the model directly into the Edit() View

Should I create some kind of Employee "partial class" for the Edit() View? to handle the IEnumerable Lists?

and set:

```
var employeeTypes = context.EmployeeTypes.Select(et => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = et.EmployeeTypeId.ToString(),
                Text = et.Type.ToString()
            });
```

---

Or should I pass them in as ViewData?

If so how to do you pass a List in as ViewData and get it to display as an @Html.DropDownList  with the Value passed in from the @Model as the defualt value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up implimenting this way, and it worked like a dream.

Controller Code:

```
 SelectList typelist = new SelectList(context.CompanyType.ToList(), "CompanyTypeId", "Type", context.CompanyType);
            ViewData["CompanyTypes"] = typelist;
```

View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["CompanyTypes"])
```

Comment: how to select the index in the edit form in this dropdown list

Answer (score 3):

There may be bugs in this code - I haven't tested it - but what you basically want to do is:

```
var etId = ???  // EmployeeTypeId from your model
var employeeTypes = context.EmployeeTypes.Select(et => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = et.EmployeeTypeId.ToString(),
            Text = et.Type.ToString(),
            Selected = et.EmployeeTypeId == etId
        });
ViewData["EmployeeTypeList"] = employeeTypes.ToList();
```

Then in your view you can do

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeType", ViewData["EmployeeTypeList"])
```

Comment: Am I missing some kind of Refernce? I am using the @Html.DropDownBox() in my Create() View just fine.

Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ShadowVenue.Models.Employee>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: This is the Sytax from my View(): <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeTypeId", ViewData["EmployeeTypeList"]) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeTypeId)
        </div>

Comment: @Timothy Green - That's funny.  The DropDownList override is there in MVC2.  I'll do some digging around in MVC3 and see what I can find.

Comment: @Timothy Green - Do you have a reference to System.Web.Mvc.Html in your project (Web.config)?