# DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC3!! I want to display a text box for my property which is of list type. I am using Razor view. In that i am using @Html.EditorFor(), but this method is not working if my property is complex like List. Also I want to display a Dropdown in my view.

Can anyone tell the solution for this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: A text box for a list property? You need to decide how you'd like to see the items in there, and then write your own code to display the data

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I want is a dropdown which will be populated from my property which is of type List<string> in my model class.

Comment: I have tried this. Inner Property does not exist. Can anyone give some other ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Property.Select(y=>y.InnerProperty))
```

will probably get you displaying what you want but you will have trouble model binding

w://

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question to this. Hope it helps you out:
[DropDown for Edit() [Razor]View, Pre-Loaded with Data from Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386357/dropdown-for-edit-razorview-pre-loaded-with-data-from-model)

Possibly this one also: 
[Create a Dropdown List for MVC3 using Entity Framework (.edmx Model) & Razor Views && Insert A Database Record to Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326515/create-a-dropdown-list-for-mvc3-using-entity-framework-edmx-model-razor-view)

Tim